# Micrometric glass beads sticking on glass or plastic funnel wall

Tags: fluid-dynamics, capillary-action

I am making a granular raft on a water-air interface. Granular rafts are made of micrometric or millimetric particles generally heavier than the liquid but still float on the interface due to their small size. The water is contained within a funnel (glass, teflon).  As I am draining water from the container, a lot of the particles are also getting stuck on the container wall (picture attached). My initial understanding was that the draining liquid is forming a thin film on the glass wall where the small particles are getting stuck by capillary bridging. But this does not explain why the same thing happens to Teflon funnels where the draining water does not form any film at all due to its hydrophobic nature. Is there any way I can reduce the sticking of the particles? [image]